# Объект типа string и объект собственноручно созданного типа имеют одинаковое строение, учитывая, что они оба ссылочного типа?

Tags: c#, строки, объекты

```
class A
{

}
class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string a = "99";
    A a2 = new A();
  }
}
```

Я читал книгу Рихтера и Голдштейна, поэтому знаю, как выглядит объект собственноручно созданного типа, при этом я знаю, что этот объект - ссылочного типа, так как класс - ссылочный тип. Но раз string тоже ссылочного типа, то он имеет такое же строение, как объект собственноручно созданного типа? Если да, то объект типа string хранит своё значение в поле или что-то типа этакого? Если нет, то в куче создаётся не объект типа string, а само значение переменной, то есть в куче просто выделяется память, а в эту память запихуется одно значение? Но тогда бы мы не смогли обращаться к методам типа object, так как не было бы таблицы методов, - значит, похожи по строению?

Я имел ввиду, имеет ли объект типа string также, как и объект собственноручно созданного типа, указатель на объект-тип, индекс блока синхронизации, таблицу методов, в которой есть EEClass и указатель на интерфейсы, и т. д. и т. п.

Comment: Есть два дома, стоят по соседству. Почтовые адреса этих домов назовем ссылками на дома. Так вот, перефразируя ваш вопрос - то, что оба дома имеют адреса, значит ли это, что дома должны иметь одинаковое строение?

Comment: Стоп. Я не говорил, что сами дома одинаковые, если имеют одинаковый вид адреса. Я имел ввиду, имеют ли дом типа string также, как и второй дом, указатель на объект-тип, индекс блока синхронизации, таблицу методов, в которой есть EEClass и указатель на интерфейсы, и т. д. и т. п.

Comment: Видимо я не до конца понял ваш вопрос. Насколько я помню - эта тема в рихтере была и, я могу ошибаться, но я всегда считал что ссылочные типы сами по себе устроены одинаково, то есть тип для строки и тип для класса будет иметь схожее строение.

Comment: Я сам думаю, что они устроены одинаково, но работает ли эта "одинаковость" со встроенным типом string? Хочу это узнать наверняка=)

Comment: Хотите узнать наверняка - проведите тесты. Метод `.GetHashCode()` вам поможет идентифицировать уникальный объект.

Comment: Мне кажется, что встроенные типы [особо не отличаются](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c) от своих, это такие же классы.

Comment: Строки имеют специфическое устройство, подробнее см. https://habr.com/en/post/165597/

Answer (score -1):

Встроенные типы С# string, long , int имеют свои
псевдонимы в .NetFramework, легко запутаться потому что C# это не только .net. Почитайте [тут](https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/difference-between-string-and-string-in-c/)
Так как все типы это потомки Object то и разницы я не вижу

Comment: Прямо говоря не вижу, как этот текст отвечает на вопросы топикстартера.

Comment: А то что это одно и тоже в .net. все это объекты и разницы нет как с ними работает .net

Comment: @AzizUmarov, в вопросе не спрашивается разница между String и string. Там скорее спрашивается про разницу между String и A

Comment: А разница между String и Object и A есть?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, в этом и состоит вопрос :-) И твой ответ на него никак не отвечает